# Question mark on wifi icon and internet not working

Tags: internet, connection, madwifi

So the question mark in the wifi icon appeared a couple days ago and it was usualy there for a couple min and then it was gone and everything was worknig fine but today it has been there and hasn't dissapeared and the wifi is not working (even tho in works in all the other devices in my home). I've tried rebooting my laptop and router multiple times and also tried a lot of solutions shown in other questions similar to mine (the main difference it that in other questions the wifi was working even when the question mark was there, not my case) like turning off the connectivity checking. I really need some help bc I need to do a lot of homework in my computer, thanks. If information about my pc is needed I'll get it but since  I don't know what's going on, I don't know what information I can put. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and my laptop is a dell inspiron.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.